# Alligning Multiple Divs in a Grid in CSS without Float

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have been trying to design a webpage consisting of multiple divs which contain images in a grid (not CSS Grid) something like this:

```html
<div class="some classes"> Some Text </div> <br>

<a href="somwhere"> 
  <div class="some classes float-left"> 
     <img src="http://someimage" height="200px" alt="An image"/> <br> 
     <div class="some other classes"> some image text </div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="somwhere"> 
  <div class="some classes float-left"> 
     <img src="http://someimage" height="200px" alt="An image"/> <br> 
     <div class="some other classes"> some image text </div>
  </div>
</a>
... many times

<footer> some footer </footer>
```

With CSS

```css
.float-left {
  float:left;
}
```

and other CSS classes are just placeholders without any meaning.

I do not know how many such divs are created since it is done automatically through a build tool according some variable parameters. I have been using `float:left` which seemed to fit the case but as as soon as I add a footer it gets embedded right inside some other classes. I suspect this is due to the usage of float. It would be helpful if someone could show me an alternate way with or without using float or even some other CSS tool but I would prefer a non-JS solution and a responsive solution.

Comment: Voting to close as the selector contains a typo (not reproduciable or caused by a typo): `.float-left: { ... }` insead of `.float-left { ... }`

Comment: @tacoshy The typo has been fixed

Comment: An alternative to the `float-hack` would be [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). However if you need to control both height and width at the same time then CSS-Grid would be the way to go. The only downside to CSS-Grid is, that it is only partially supported by IE (which will be deprecated starting at the 16th August 2021). You can also use `minmax` in combination with `auto-fit` and  `auto-fill` to achieve responsivness.

Comment: @tacoshy IE compatibility is the least of concerns right now. However, in the past I have played around with CSS Grid but in CSS Grid you have to specify the number of column/rows but say I am viewing in a mobile it just seemed to not work. I have been unsuccessful in implementing it here as I said I have an astronomical divs to align here so I cannot do manual alignment.

Comment: read again. you dont need to specify the ammount of columns in css-grid. You can use `auto-fit` and `auto-fill` in combination with `minmax` instead. You define how wide an element should be minimum and amximum and it will fit as many elements in the row as would fit.

Comment: @tacoshy Could you make an answer with that becase I really can't reproduce what you are saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I already said, you can use `auto-fit` or `auto-fill` in combination with `minmax` to create a responsive grid that doesnt care how many items are present.

for that you can apply to the wrapping element (it also can be the body):
 `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(minimum width value, maximum width value));`

To have the footer always below all the images and span the entire width you can use:
 `footer { grid-column: 1 / -1; }`

This approach will fit as many images or other elements in a row as the screen fits. I added a `resize` property to the snippet so you can resize the element and see how the grid responds to it:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

footer {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}


/* for demonstration purpose only */
.grid {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 104px;
  max-width: 100%; 
}

.grid > * {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 20vh;
  color: white;
}

.grid > div:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.grid > div:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.grid > div:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

.grid > footer {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>

  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you need to write

```
.float-left {
    float: left;
}
```

instead of

```
.float-left:{
    float: left;
}
```

You have to remove the extra `:`.

Comment: typo caused issues are reason for closure. such questions should not be answered but commented instead!

Comment: i don't have the privilege to comment on other's post at the moment

Comment: I'm aware that you unlock the comment option at 50 reputation. However you trying to bypass an existing limitation by mis-using the answer option. Bypassing an existing limitation is a very bad excuse.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. In your wrapper div you want to add this CSS

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b"
    "c d";
  align-items: start;
}
```

Then for each of your grid 'div's you can add this CSS to each of them

```
.item1 {
  grid-area: a;
}
.item2 {
  grid-area: b;
}
.item3 {
  grid-area: c;
}
.item4 {
  grid-area: d;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting but like I mentioned in the question the number of divs I cannot control it is changing every time I run the build tool so I don't think I can use this solution, Besides, the number of divs can go over 120 -130 so defining grid-areas would not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add all your elements in a div and use align attribute

your_elements

that is the best and simplest way if you don't want to use float